# OCaml makefile dependency problem

Tags: makefile, ocaml

I am using OCaml Makefile for a project I am working on and I have the folowing modules

`DynamicTree.ml`

`Huffman_Dynamic.ml` which uses `DynamicTree`

`Huffman_Static.ml`

`main.ml` which uses both *`Huffman_Static`* and *`Huffman_Dynamic`*.

This is my make file :

```
# put here the names of your source files (in the right order)
SOURCES = huffman_static.ml dynamictree.ml huffman_dynamic.ml main.ml

# the name of the resulting executable
RESULT  = huffman

# generate type information (.annot files)
ANNOTATE = yes

# make target (see manual) : byte-code, debug-code, native-code
all: native-code

include OCamlMakefile
```

When I try to make the project, I get an `Unbound value DynamicTree.create_anchor_leaf` that results from `ocamlopt -c -dtypes huffman_dynamic.ml` generated by Makefile.

The Ocaml Makefile wepage [states that it generates](http://hg.ocaml.info/release/ocaml-make/raw-file/release-6.29.3/README.txt) automatically dependencies, am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a log of what happens when you run `make` after a `make clean`?  That could provide some insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the capitalization of your name correct ? In your post you use both `DynamicTree.ml` and `dynamictree.ml`.

Are you sure the issue comes from the Makefile ? Is there really a `create_anchor_leaf` function exported by `DynamicTree.ml` ? No `.mli` hiding it ?

Comment: Thanks, that was the capitalization for T that causes the problem